# Dataframe to Dictionary Guidance

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataset that I'm trying to clean and turn into a dictionary.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVNpM.png)

The result of this dictionary should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqFi5.png)

I'm not sure what the best method is to take the data that I have and produce only one dictionary with four key/value pairs. I'm aware that pandas has a .to_dict() function to convert dataframes into dictionaries but am not sure that this is the best method. Could a for loop work?

My code is below:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
def proportion_of_education():
    # your code goes here
    df = pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv', usecols=['SEQNUMC','EDUC1'])
    df['less than high school'] = ''
    df.loc[(df['EDUC1']== 1), 'less than high school']= '.02'
    df['high school'] = ''
    df.loc[(df['EDUC1']==2), 'high school']= '.04'
    df.loc[(df['EDUC1']==3), 'more than high school but not college']= '.02' 
    df['college']= ''
    df.loc[(df['EDUC1']==4), 'college']= '.02'
    new_df= df.set_index(['EDUC1']).drop(['SEQNUMC'], axis=1)
    
    print(new_df.head(10))


    
proportion_of_education()
```

Comment: Can you format your question so it's a little easier to read? I think you need some extra linebreak/returns to get your pictures to show up in your question and the import statements to show up in your code block. As for your question, you probably want to avoid a for loop, unless your dataframe is small (in which case the performance hit doesn't really matter).

Comment: Also, how does the dataframe index play into what you're doing with the dictionary output, or does it?